# Syncing One Online and Multiple Offline Versions of the Same Schema DB in Rails

Tags: database, postgresql, merge, replication, offline

**SETUP**
I have three instances running of my app deployed in three separate geographical locations running locally (since Internet connections are not reliable). 
I have one master instance of the app running on DigitalOcean.

I would like to sync the local databases with the master database daily.

**MY CURRENT APPROACH**
I have a cron job scheduled to pull the data from the local databases and upload them into a database running on a DigitalOcean VPS. My concern is that the id columns of the three local dbs will conflict resulting in an incorrect merge in the online master database.

I am running Rails 4.1 with Ruby 2.0 using Postgres as my DB.

I am open to any solutions that come up with a relatively simple way of keeping the databases in sync.

Thank you

Comment: Without showing table definitions or the queries you are running you'll be hard pressed to get a relevant answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution would be to have all your unique autonumbering one column ID keys to consist of 2 different columns. An "ServerID" and an auto numbering ID. It makes your design more complicated but you never have to worry of non unique keys.